# Deploy different branches to different Heroku applications with Travis-CI

Tags: github, heroku, travis-ci

In my github repo I have two branches: `master` and `release`. So currently having this `.travis.yml` configuration:

```
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: [MY-ENCRYPTED-KEY]
  app: myapp
  on:
    repo: helloworld/myapp
    branch: release
  run:
    - restart
  skip_cleanup: true
```

makes it possible to deploy a heroku app named `myapp` from the `release` branch.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku/#deploying-custom-application-names), I can specify a custom application name like so (`dev` and `production` keys):

```
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: [MY-ENCRYPTED-KEY]
  app:
   dev: myapp-dev
   production: myapp
  on:
    repo: helloworld/myapp
    branch: release
  run:
    - restart
  skip_cleanup: true
```

### Now the question is:

How can I specify the branch for each app? Like:

- `master` branch `->` `myapp-dev` (dev)
- `release` branch `->` `myapp` (production)

The documentation is not clear on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not stated anywhere in the documentation, but it turned out the key names in the `app` section actually correspond to branch names:

```
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: [MY-ENCRYPTED-KEY]
  app:
    master: myapp-dev
    release: myapp
  on:
    repo: helloworld/myapp
  run:
    - restart
  skip_cleanup: true
```